# How to create a collection of objects in SpringBoot without having the database?

Tags: java, spring, model

I am new to SpringBoot. I don't know how to create a few objects of the same type in the way that enables to use this objects later for example in the controller.

Let's say I would like to create collection/list of objects (let's say collection of Rabbits) when the application starts:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            // I would like to create here a collection
            // or a list of objects (let's say collection of Rabbits)
        }

}
```

I would like to have the possibility to use this objects later in the controller to get some information (obtained for example by index in the list).

What is the right way to keep state of my model without having a database?

Comment: You have to create List bean with elements and then autowired where you want

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring synchronization issues.

You can create a List and inject into your controllers.

or what I like to do is wrap that in a repository. This insulates you from the underlying datasource and it can be changed later.

Note that synchronization is important for this type of data structure as you can have many threads updating the repository.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitRepository rabbitRepository() {
        RabbitRepository rabbitRepository = new RabbitRepository();
        rabbitRepository.add("Bugs");
        rabbitRepository.add("Flopsy");
        return rabbitRepository;
    }

    public static class RabbitRepository {
        private List<Rabbit> rabbits = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Rabbit>());

        public List<Rabbit> getAll() {
            return rabbits;
        }

        public Rabbit add(String rabbitName) {
            Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit(rabbitName);
            this.rabbits.add(rabbit);
            return rabbit;
        }

        public Optional<Rabbit> findById(int id) {
            return this.rabbits.stream().filter(r-> r.getId() == id).findFirst();
        }

    }

    public static class Rabbit {
        private final String name;

        private final int id;

        private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        public Rabbit(String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.id = counter.incrementAndGet();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }


    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/rabbits")
    public static class RabbitController {
        private final RabbitRepository repository;

        public RabbitController(final RabbitRepository repository) {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        @GetMapping
        public List<Rabbit> getAll() {
            return repository.getAll();
        }

        @PostMapping("/{name}")
        //You can also use requestparam / requestbody and probably should
        public Rabbit addRabbit(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
            return repository.add(name);
        }

        @GetMapping("/id/{id}")
        public Optional<Rabbit> findById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
            return repository.findById(id);
        }

    }

}
```

Curl tests

```
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/rabbits            
    [{"name":"Bugs","id":1},{"name":"Flopsy","id":2}]%
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/rabbits/id/2       
    {"name":"Flopsy","id":2}%                                                       
➜  ~ curl -XPOST localhost:8080/rabbits/Babs
    {"name":"Babs","id":3}%                                                         
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/rabbits            
    [{"name":"Bugs","id":1},{"name":"Flopsy","id":2},{"name":"Babs","id":3}]%
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spring you need to create objects in the context of spring, otherwise spring created instances can't find them. A solution can be putting them in a class annotated with [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) and retrieve them with the annotation `@Autowired`.
The annotation `@Configuration`:

> Indicates that a class declares one or more **@Bean methods** and may be **processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions** and service requests for those beans at runtime.

You can use it as follow:

```
 @Configuration
 public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyClass getMyClass() {
       MyClass myClass = ...
       ...
       return myClass;
    }
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  private MyClass myClass;

  public void method() {
     // Use myClass instance as you like
  }
}
```

You can also generate a standard `java.util.List`, but in this case is better to give a name to the bean generated, for example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean("myname") // To give an explicit name to the List
    public List getMyList() {
       List myList = ...
       ...
       return myList;
    }
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myname")  // To retrieve a List with a specific name
  private List myList;

  public void method() {
     // Use myList instance as you like
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use the name of the bean it works automatically with a bean name of "getMyList" in your case. Also the qualifier is also magically not needed if the name of the list is the same. Though I dislike that magic.

Comment: @Wes You are true, but a List is a very generic object and you can use libraries that generate other Bean of the same type or your code can do the same, so in this case it is better to give it a name to be sure to extract the right bean.

Comment: Agreed. I just noted it. Its still good practice to have the name of the method the same as the name in the bean if possible as it doesn't violate the principal of least supprise. In your case (assuming the bean name was myname) I would have used the signature `public List<T> myname()`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this i guess !

```
@Component
public class RabbitListHolder {
   private List<Rabbit> rabbits = new ArrayList<Rabbit>
   public void initializeList(){
      rabbits.add(new Rabbit('white', 3));
      ...
   }

}

@Controller
public class RabbitsRessource{
 @Autowired
RabbitListHolder rabbitListHolder;
 ...
@GetMapping("/rabbits")
public List<Rabbits> getRabbits(){
  rabbitListHolder.initializeList();
  return rabbitListHolder.getRabbits();
}
}
```